# Case-insensitive match method

Tags: java, case-sensitive

While I'm reading [Holub on Patterns](http://www.holub.com/goodies/patterns/), I found code I cannot understand.

The code looks like this, and if you want, you can read part of book in [here](http://books.google.co.kr/books?id=1e-4ovUlZy0C&pg=PA263&lpg=PA263&dq=holub+on+pattern+case+insensitive&source=bl&ots=heiqZmTP9V&sig=XA3Gm9-zeI4dLQcw2MPrLDSCe3k&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Nn1dUJ7_Ea2fiAfGgYH4Cg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=holub%20on%20pattern%20case%20insensitive&f=false).

```
/** Matches a simple symbol that doesn't have to be on a "word"
 *  boundary; punctuation, for example. SimpleToken
 *  is very efficient, but does not recognize characters in
 *  a case-insensitive way, as does {@link WordToken} and
 *  {@link RegexToken}.
 *
 *  @include /etc/license.txt
 */

public class SimpleToken implements Token
{   
  private final  String     pattern;

  /** Create a token.
   *  @param pattern a string that defines a literal-match lexeme.
   */

  public SimpleToken( String pattern )
  { this.pattern = pattern.toLowerCase();
  }

  public boolean match( String input, int offset )
  { return input.toLowerCase().startsWith( pattern, offset );
  }

  public String lexeme()  { return pattern; }
  public String toString(){ return pattern; }
}
```

The comment(and book) says the SimpleToken class "**does not** recognize characters in a case-insensitive way", but the `match` method compares pattern in lower case and it means it **does** recognize in case-insensitive way.

What am I missing here?

**Edit**

I searched this in [errata list](http://neuroning.com/pages/holub_errata)(not official though), but there wasn't. And it's hard to regard this as errata. It says about this several times.

Comment: Did you run this example and verified?

Comment: Yes, I did. It was apparently case-insensitive.

Comment: How much errata did you found?

Answer (score 1):

I can assure you that this code matches case *insensitively*.

I don't care what the comment or book says.

Answer (score 1):

> And it's hard to regard this as errata.

None the less, the book is incorrect.  The code plainly does match tokens in a case insensitive fashion, and your experiments confirm this.  Even authors (and their editors) make mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the search `is case-insensitive`. What all I can surmise is that there `can be bugs everywhere`, in `javadocs` `and in books` which only are build only by looking at `javadocs` (and `not at exact code`).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do the matching:

1. Compare characters, one at a time and allow for a lower case letter to be treated as the equal of the same letter, only uppercase. If each of those character level matches are equal then the whole strings match.
2. Lowercase both string and pattern at the outset and then perform an exact character match.

The first case is case insensitive because the "is this character the same as that character" question ignores the case of the letter.  The second can be case sensitive because the test does consider case, although that issue is moot because you changed both strings to lower case outside of the test.